# Mksapi to get password from preferences

Tags: java, mks, mks-integrity

I have an application that connects to integrity through the java mks api. To test the application functionalities I hardcoded the user and the password for my computer, but now after testing I want to make the app generic so more users can use it.

Normally, each user has a user (this information I can get it from ENV) and a password configured in the `Integrity` interface. Is there a possibility to tell the `mksapi` to get the password from those preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to get the password from Client preferences.
You don't need to have the password if the connection already exist and you are using localintegration.

e.g.

```
si projects --hostname={SI_HOST} --port={SI_PORT} --user={USERNAME}
```

The previous command will work without password if there is an active connection for the provided info: `{USERNAME}@{SI_HOST}:{SI_PORT}`

Another option is to use a user with impersonate permission.
if you cannot use any of this option, the only way is to prompt the user for a password.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I still have one question, by an "active connection" do you mean an open `Integrity` instance?

Comment: Yes. If you already have the Integrity client opened and there is a connection active, all ommand will work without password. But this will work only if you are using Local Integration Point

Comment: With active connection I mean you are connected to the mks server via Integrity Client.